# How does the expression "x & (x + (1 << n))" work?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

The text I was reading says that:

> x & (x + (1 << n)) = x, with the run of set bits (possibly length 0) starting at bit n cleared.

I tried putting different values in the python console and saw that:

```
>>> 5 & (5 + (1 << 2))
1
```

However, when I tried putting in other different values instead of 2, I got 5 as the answer. I tried putting in values from 1 to 7.

I tried deriving the expression but I couldn't. 
What must be a reasonable explanation for the same? And how does it work?

Comment: what's it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried putting in values from 1 to 7 [for n]

`n = 0` is also fine. Actually let's look at that case first. So `x & (x + 1)`.

If `x` is odd, then `x` is of the form a01<sup>k</sup> (some bit-string `a`, followed by a zero, followed by `k` ones). Adding 1 to it would carry through all the trailing ones and turn it into a10<sup>k</sup>. And-ing that with `x` cancels the old trailing ones with the new trailing zeroes, and that new 1 that appeared with the old 0. `a` stays the same. In other words: the trailing ones were reset.

If `x` is even, then adding 1 to it does not carry, the only effect is that the least significant bit becomes set. The AND with `x` then resets that bit again. Overall nothing happens.

If `n` is not zero, then it's as if the `n` least significant bits aren't there. The addition doesn't affect them, therefore the AND doesn't either. So in total, `x & (x + (1 << n))` can be described as "if there is a run of ones starting at position `n`, zero out that run, otherwise do nothing".

A potentially interesting variant is `x & (x + (x & -x))`, which first uses `x & -x` to get a mask of the least significant set bit and then proceeds the same as the original expression. That would find the first run of ones and reset it.